# problem with custom url to the featured image

Tags: html, wordpress

I have used a wordpress plugin (Add Featured Image Custom Link) to insert custom url to the featured image.

I have two functionalities in my portfolio:

1. when the user click on image it will popup the image; this is working properly.
2. the anchor tag I have used for  the link which I have added to featured image I want to redirect to the website of which I have added the link on featured image

How do I do #2

```html
<div class="option inner">
  <div>
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php
      $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
    ?> 
    <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="fa fa-search mfp-image"></a>
    <a href="" class="fa fa-link"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. Add punctuation too. It is really hard to guess what you want. What is `the plugin`? for example

Comment: plug name Add Featured Image Custom Link  my problem is that i have added portfolio to the site  https://vitsol.net/ u can check the portfolio section down in the site and i have used to icon on hover over the picture one is for search and the other is for the url of the site when the user click on search it open the image popup it work properly and the second one is the link icon where when the user click on it then it redirect the user to the website (the url which i have added to the featured image)

Comment: Please see my update to your question. I added spaces and punctuation. It is now much easier to read. What do you mean by "redirect to the website of which I have added the link on featured image" ? you have TWO links and the second does not go anywhere

Comment: yes sir i have not added any back-end code to the second anchor tag because i do not know what to add here  so i have added this link https://boostingclub.net/ to the featured image through admin dashboard now i want the user click  on this anchor tag <a href="" class="fa fa-link"></a>  it will go the boosting club sir u can check the site url https://vitsol.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution by one way i think it is not the proper way
that is, inplace of `<a href="" class="fa fa-link"></a>` i wrote the funciton the_content
and inside editor of the wordpress i use the custome html like this

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" class="fa fa-link"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the input from the (Add Featured Image Custom Link) WordPress Plugin it's easy. This code will add the link if the input is not empty.

```
<div class="option inner">
  <div>
    <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
    <?php
      $cust_li_fi_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_url_image', true );
      if( $cust_li_fi_value ) { ?>
             <a href="<?php echo $cust_li_fi_value;?>" class="fa fa-link"></a> 
      <?php } 
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cheers,
Happy Coding :)